# What's wrong with get request (axios)

Tags: reactjs, http, axios

I've been trying to send a request for half a day, but for some reason refuses to work. In postmen, the data comes in fine. What's wrong? Looked through a ton of options for solving this problem, rewrote the code in different ways, but refuses to return the data.

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import * as axios from 'axios';
 
function App() {
 
  let auth = { 'TGH-Api-Key': 'my_key' }
 
  axios.get("http://api-site.net/api/value/1", { headers: { auth } })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      debugger;
    })
 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
 
export default App;
```

Comment: What is not working? Are you never seeing the `console.log(res)` output and hit the breakpoint? Have you rendered your `App` component anywhere?

Comment: And the way you set the headers is probably wrong: `headers: { auth }` will set headers to an object with a single key `auth` with a value of `{ 'TGH-Api-Key': 'my_key' }` so you may want to spread that out like this `headers: { ...auth }`.
And after you got the request working and hitting the breakpoint you will need [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to wrap the fetching code and [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to store the response data

Comment: I can't see console.log () and debugger. The request is not sent, but the component is rendered when the project starts. I put the debugger before the request and everything worked.

Comment: {... auth} shows the same result.

Comment: You should see a request. But anyway you shouldn't send requests from within the render function (although we should still see the request happening). Wrap it in a `useEffect` like this and see if it changes anything: `useEffect( () => axios.get("http://api-site.net/api/value/1", { headers: { auth } }).then(res => { console.log(res); debugger;}), []);`

Comment: Same result, no change.

Comment: And you don't even see any request beeing sent in the browsers dev tools?

Comment: i get error - Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http: // api' from origin 'http: // localhost: 3000' has been blocked by CORS